# Directive declaration format

Tags: angularjs

All:

I am new to angular, right now,I try to declare a directive :

```
var app = angular.module("vp", []);
app.directive("outter", ["$compile", "$scope", function($compile, $scope){
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    compile: function(tEL, attrs){
      return {
        post: function(scope, EL, attrs){

        }
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

and in my html:

```
<body ng-app="vp">
    <outter></outter>
</body>
```

But I keep getting error like:
***http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20outterDirective***

Could anyone give me some clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope is not a service, thus not something you can inject. You have access to the scope in the link function.

You should change you directive definition to:

```
app.directive("outter", ["$compile" function($compile){
```

Comment: thanks for help. I wonder how can I know if the injection is a service or not? I am thinking why we can inject the $scope into controller function but not in directive function?